# Accessing hash value from hash directly VS from variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, hash

I have a question:

Suppose we have a hash

```
hash = {:key1 => "value1", :key2 => "value2"}
```

what is more efficient way to access **"value1"** it multiple times.

Is it with directly

```
hash[:key1]
```

OR

```
val = hash[:key1]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually something you can check by yourself:

```
gem install benchmark-ips
```

```rb
require 'benchmark/ips'
hash = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2"}
Benchmark.ips do |x| 
 x.report("assign") { foo =  hash[:key1] }
 x.report("direct") { hash[:key1] }
end
```

and run it:

```
Warming up --------------------------------------
              assign     1.644M i/100ms                                                            
              direct     1.730M i/100ms                                   
Calculating -------------------------------------                         
              assign     15.884M (± 4.1%) i/s -     80.534M in   5.078824s
              direct     16.811M (± 5.2%) i/s -     84.780M in   5.056902s
```

As expected, what you call direct (not assigning value to a variable) is slightly faster, but not by much (~6%)

You can learn more about this benchmarking tool here: https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips

You can use this tool in any way you want, just makes sure you're measuring what you want, for example if you want to know if memoized variable is faster than a hash, you can do this

```
require 'benchmark/ips'
hash = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2"}
temp = hash[:key1]
Benchmark.ips do |x| 
 x.report("temp") { temp }
 x.report("hash") { hash[:key1] }
end
```

Or, as you mentioned in a comment, the values are huge, try this

```rb
require 'benchmark/ips'
hash = {key1: "x" * 10_000, key2: "value2"}
temp = hash[:key1]
Benchmark.ips do |x| 
 x.report("temp") { temp }
 x.report("hash") { hash[:key1] }
end
```

Or if you meant that the has itself is huge (i.e. a lot of keys), just prepare your hash to resemble your real word problem and run the benchmark again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what if we have a huge key value pairs inside a hash. Wont it take time every-time to fetch and access. Let me know your thoughts please

Comment: I think you are comparing apples with pears with your benshmark. The idea of the OP seems to be: If you need the hash value several times, does it make sense to access it first by looking it up via the key and store it in a variable for later reuse, or access it directly every time. This is, to compare `hash[:key1]; hash[:key1]; hash[:key1]; ...` with `foo = hash[:key1]; foo; foo; ...`.

Comment: @ParambirKaur I think you should provide a bigger context of what you're doing. Performance tuning is not like a bug where you can isolate the minimal code to reproduce and discuss it. If the values in hash are huge - we need to know how huge. To be able to discuss how it impacts the whole program performance - we need to know how it is used (are you inserting it in the file, sending over a network, searching a particular string inside). Feel free to update your question and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is, if you need to use a value stored in a hash multiple times,  say in a loop, is it faster to store the value in a variable or just access the value directly from the hash when it is needed.

Accessing the value in a hash is generally is O(1),  but in the worst case can be O(n). In addition at the very least accessing the hash would require sending the key through the hashing function, so I think in general extracting the value once and then referring would be faster.

Here is a somewhat extreme case were the value is needed 1000 times,  but you can see from the results of the built in benchmark module, accessing the variable is faster than accessing the hash.  And since for this simple hash the access is almost certainty O(1), the difference is probably only due to the fact that the hashing function must be called on the key before getting the value.

```rb
require 'benchmark'

hash = {:key1 => "value1", :key2 => "value2"} 

val = nil 

Benchmark.bmbm do |x| 
    x.report { val = hash[:key1] }
end

puts "*****"
val = hash[:key1]

Benchmark.bmbm do |x| 
    x.report { 1000.times { val } }
    x.report { 1000.times { hash[:key1] } }
end
```

```
Rehearsal ------------------------------------
   0.000006   0.000002   0.000008 (  0.000003)
--------------------------- total: 0.000008sec

       user     system      total        real
   0.000006   0.000000   0.000006 (  0.000004)
*****
Rehearsal ------------------------------------
   0.000051   0.000000   0.000051 (  0.000051)
   0.000063   0.000000   0.000063 (  0.000062)
--------------------------- total: 0.000114sec

       user     system      total        real
   0.000048   0.000011   0.000059 (  0.000054)
   0.000082   0.000000   0.000082 (  0.000077)
```